# How to use messageembed correctly?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**Hello i have problem:**

```
TypeError: MessageEmbed is not a constructor
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\index.js:34:21)
    at Client.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1173:51)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\patry\Desktop\MythicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:988:14)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:393:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

**Code:**

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});
const prefix = '$'; // Możesz dostosować prefix komendy
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'wyslij') {
      // Sprawdź, czy użytkownik podał odpowiednie argumenty
      if (args.length < 3) {
        return message.reply('Za mało argumentów. Użyj: $wyslij IDkanalu Tresc Kolor');
      }

      const channelID = args[0];
      const content = args[1];
      const color = args[2].toLowerCase(); // Przekonwertuj kolor na małe litery

      // Sprawdź, czy kanał istnieje
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
      if (!channel) {
        return message.reply('Podany kanał nie istnieje.');
      }

      // Stwórz wiadomość embed
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(color)
        .setDescription(content);

      // Wyślij wiadomość embed na wskazany kanał
      channel.send(embed);
    }
  }
});
```

**I don't know how to do it, in discord docs they do exports in some module and I don't understand it**

sorry i must bypass
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version, you should use [`EmbedBuilder`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/EmbedBuilder) instead.